# Migrating to the latest FSharp.Core generates warnings

Tags: f#, compiler-warnings

I've just migrated my project to use FSharp.Core 6.0.3 instead of 6.0.1.
I noticed that now in my code there are warnings every time I refer to `uint32` with a unit of measure. More specificaly:

- `LanguagePrimitives.UInt32WithMeasure` function
- `uint32<cm>` as a parameter type

I guess it's safe to set a compile flag to ignore this warning, but I'd like to understand what has happened and why this is now considered a problem.

The exact warning message is: `FS0057: Experimental library feature, requires '--langversion:preview'. This warning can be disabled using '--nowarn:57' or '#nowarn "57"'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older versions of F# only supported units of measure for [signed integer values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/units-of-measure) (and floating point).

According to [this comment on an F# language issue](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/901#issuecomment-834133386), units of measure are now supported experimentally for unsigned integers as well.

In playing around with an example, I noticed that you can avoid the warning by using `uint<cm>` instead of `uint32<cm>`, but I'm not sure if this is intentional.

Comment: That's true. I'm just surprised that FSharp.Core `6.0.1` does **NOT** generate this warning.

Answer (score 1):

My $0.02 to this: I've reviewed the `fsharp` GH repo and found the declaration of `LanguagePrimitives.UInt32WithMeasure`.

```ml
[<Experimental("Experimental library feature, requires '--langversion:preview'")>]
val inline UInt32WithMeasure: input: uint -> uint<'Measure>
```

However, the `Experimental` attribute was added in [this](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/commit/85fe2809db9c106d3c630c74dbe806eb8b9b09c9) commit, so I guess that `FSharp.Core` 6.0.1 must have been created before that and therefore it doesn't report the warning.